Unable to access data element through the jquery dom
I want to create variables $eventDuration and $employeeRate, however, for some reason I am getting an error in the console saying they are undefined.
Here is my script code:
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submitChange').click(function (ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        var cell = ev.target;
        
        $eventDuration = $(this).data('eventduration');
        $employeeRate = $(this).data('employeerate');
        $usertype = $(this).data('employeetype');
        $cellId = $(cell).attr('id');
        $eventId = $(cell).data('eventid');
        $employeeId = $(cell).data('employeeid');
        if ($cellId === 'green-cell') {
            $action = 'remove';
        } else {
            $action = 'add';
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/ajax_request.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                action: $action,
                eventId: $eventId,
                employeeId: $employeeId
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response === 'removed') { // remove an employee
                    $(cell).removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'yellow-cell'); 
                    if($usertype === 'Server') { // remove server 
                        $(".sum_servers").each(function(){
                            if($(this).attr('data-eventid')==$eventId){
                                $sumServer = parseInt($(this).text());
                                $sumServer--;
                                $(this).text($sumServer)
                            }
                        })
                        $(".sum_staff").each(function(){ // add staff member
                            if($(this).attr('data-eventid')==$eventId){
                                $sumStaff = parseInt($(this).text());
                                $sumStaff--;
                                $(this).text($sumStaff)
                            }
                        })
                    } else { // remove preparer 
                        $(".sum_preparers").each(function(){ 
                            if($(this).attr('data-eventid')==$eventId){
                                $sumPreparers = parseInt($(this).text());
                                $sumPreparers--;
                                $(this).text($sumPreparers)
                            }
                        })
                        $(".sum_staff").each(function(){ 
                            if($(this).attr('data-eventid')==$eventId){
                                $sumStaff = parseInt($(this).text());
                                $sumStaff--;
                                $(this).text($sumStaff)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    
                    $(".sum_rate").each(function(){
                        if($(this).attr('data-eventid')==$eventId){
                            $sumRate = parseFloat($(this).text().replace('$', ''));
                            $sumRate = $sumRate - (eventDuration*employeeRate);
                            $(this).text($sumRate)
                        }
                    })
                } else { // add an employee
                    $(cell).removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'green-cell');
                    if($usertype === 'Server') { // add server 
                        $(".sum_servers").each(function(){
                            if($(this).attr('data-eventid')==$eventId){
                                $sumServer = parseInt($(this).text());
                                $sumServer++;
                                $(this).text($sumServer)
                            }
                        })
                        
                        $(".sum_staff").each(function(){
                            if($(this).attr('data-eventid')==$eventId){
                                $sumStaff = parseInt($(this).text());
                                $sumStaff++;
                                $(this).text($sumStaff)
                            }
                        })
                    } else { // add preparer 
                        $(".sum_preparers").each(function(){
                            if($(this).attr('data-eventid')==$eventId){
                                $sumPreparers = parseInt($(this).text());
                                $sumPreparers++;
                                $(this).text($sumPreparers)
                            }
                        })
                        $(".sum_staff").each(function(){
                            if($(this).attr('data-eventid')==$eventId){
                                $sumStaff = parseInt($(this).text());
                                $sumStaff++;
                                $(this).text($sumStaff)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    })
});
</script>

Here is the cell data I am trying to access (class="submitChange" at the bottom)
<tr>
    <th scope='row'><?php echo $row['lastname'] . ", " . $row['firstname']; ?></th>
    <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['usertype']; ?></td>
    <?php
    foreach ($events_array as $event) { 
        $event_date = $event['date'];
        $employee_id = $row['id'];
        
        // Check if employee has a vacation day
        $vacation_day = false;
        foreach ($vacation_dates[$employee_id] as $vacation_date) {
            if ($vacation_date == $event_date) {
                $vacation_day = true;
                break; 
            }
        }
        
        // Check if employee is working that day
        $sql_check_worker = "SELECT * FROM Workers WHERE employee={$row['id']} AND event={$event['id']}";
        $result_check_worker = $smeConn->query($sql_check_worker);
        if ($result_check_worker->num_rows > 0) { // displays cell color if employee is working or not
            $serverSum++;
            $cellColorId = 'green-cell';
        } else {
            $cellColorId = 'yellow-cell';
        }
        ?>
        <?php if ($vacation_day) { 
            echo "<td class='vacation'></td>"; 
        } else {
            echo "<td class='submitChange' id='$cellColorId' data-employeerate='{$row['rate']}' data-eventduration='{$event['duration']}' data-employeetype='{$row['usertype']}' data-eventid='{$event['id']}' data-employeeid='{$row['id']}'></td>";
        }
        ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <td><?php echo $serverSum; ?></td>
</tr>

The cell for total cost which I am attempting to update, if it's relevant:
<!-- TOTAL COST FOR A COLUMN -->
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">TOTAL COST</th>
    <td class="black-cell">*BLACK*</td>
    <?php 
    foreach ($events_array as $event) {
        $event_id = $event['id'];
        $sql_total_cost = "SELECT SUM(rate * duration) AS total_cost FROM Workers 
                           INNER JOIN Employees ON Workers.employee = Employees.id 
                           INNER JOIN Events ON Workers.event = Events.id 
                           WHERE Workers.event = $event_id";
        $result_total_cost = $smeConn->query($sql_total_cost);
        $row_total_cost = $result_total_cost->fetch_assoc();
        $total_cost = $row_total_cost['total_cost'];
        ?>
        <td class='sum_rate' data-eventId='<?php echo $event_id;?>'><?php echo '$' . round($total_cost, 2); ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
    <td class="black-cell">*BLACK*</td>
</tr>

I am confused because I am able to create the $usertype variable the exact same way. But why am I unable to create $employeeRate or $eventDuration?

Check the browser's console for any potential javascript error(s), and inspect the page source to see if the data is as expected with the element attributes.

The console is throwing an error because it says the variables are undefined.

Ok, so then inspect the page source to see how the <td> element with the submitChange looks in the rendered HTML.

Nevermind, this was a stupid question. I literally just forgot the '$' in the sumRate calculation.

Hey, no worries, believe most of us have done the same at one point or another, glad you found the issue .

I changed this
$sumRate = $sumRate - (eventDuration*employeeRate);

to this
$sumRate = $sumRate - ($eventDuration*$employeeRate);

